# jQuery $.load() sends a GET request multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

There's some code that looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    sendAGetRequest();
}
```

Periodically, on production, the GET request is being sent multiple times. I can see this using a packet sniffer.

This isn't reproducible locally.

There's a couple of similar questions on here but they don't seem to be much use.

What I'd like to know is:

- Why does the function sendAGetRequest() get called multiple times?
- What sort of things could cause this to only happen on production and not local?

I suspect the problem to be `$(window).load` and am considering changing this to `$(document).ready`. Is that a good call? As I said, I can't reproduce the problem locally and I wouldn't want to upload something to live without knowing whether it might actually fix things or not.

Comment: Not enough information to say either way. Instead of a packet sniffer, have you tried `console.log()`ing to see if the JS itself is running multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(window).load will only be triggered when page is fully loaded including pictures. While $(document).ready will be triggerred when the whole DOM is ready. This is a much better point to trigger such request as you don't have to wait for the whole resources to be loaded.  i am not sure why the function is called multiple times, although in theory it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the event that the `load()` function that attaches the event handler is getting called multiple times. Every time you call `load()`, another function handler will get attached, and all of those handlers will get called when the load event fires.

Using `document.ready` is a good call, but won't help you if the above is true.